# Scrape from site, which has CloudFlare (BeautifulSoup, Request)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am unable to scrape data from website, that uses CloudFlare.
I always get urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable
Can you show me the way to pass the CloudFlare protection?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
#Website url was changed to ####, because it is secret
url = '#######'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
   'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
   'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
   'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
   'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

req = Request(url,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

print(soup)
```

Can you explain me every step, please

Comment: `import requests; page = requests(url).content` often works, without the need to do anything more elaborate.

Comment: @BillBell, Hi. Can you show me a sample, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes **requests** will work even when urllib does not.

```
import requests
import bs4
url = ... a secret
page = requests.get(url).content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
```

If this does not work then I would try **selenium**. There are numerous examples of how to use it here on StackOverflow. I can't offer suggestions because I don't have the url you want to work with.

Comment: Cfscrape library helped me

Comment: Interesting! I must try it.

Comment: Did you mean requests.get(url)?  requests(url) does not work